# python in bottle framework- no able to access the uploaded file path

Tags: python, bottle

HTML form :

```
<input type="file" name="upload"/>
file = request.files.get(upload)
```

Lets say i have apple.xls in this path : c:/desktop/tempfolder/Apple.xls

step 1: I am clicking browse button to upload the file

```
name,ext= os.path.splittext(upload.filename)
```

It gives filename and its extension

I need file path mentioned in the input box like c:/desktop/tempfolder/Apple.xls

When i tried using my project name is Appbuilder

`pat=os.path.abspath(upload.filename)`

It gives c:/desktop/tempfolder/(applicationname:Appbuilder)/Apple.xls

Comment: Why do you need the _path_ to the file on the client machine? Aren't the file's contents enough?

Comment: i need to pass the  file path in the function to process the file, where that function is existing function

Comment: Client-server architectures (web servers) do not assume that the client is on the same machine as the server.  So HTTP may not be the right technology for your task; can you just run a script instead?